# angular data-tables, filtering from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I am using the andglar directive data-tables (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) to bring in and display some information in table form and I'm trying to add a little bit too it. I am just trying to add a few buttons that would filter the json object i bring in a bit further than the table currently does.

So for example, I have one row that has US states, and 10 buttons for 10 different states, I want to click the button and have it filter out all options with that state. I am attempting to set the button with an ng-click(state name here) on the button and then filter the scope with all the data table info.  The problem I am having is I cannot seem to find the scope anywhere that has all the json info binded to the table.

I am doing pretty much exactly this - http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax

So what i am trying to do is dig through the scopes with the angular dev tool for chrome. I call in the info like so

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('/listAllLessons')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withTableTools('https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/raw/master/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')
    .withTableToolsButtons([
            'copy',
            'print',
            'csv', 
            'xls', 
            'pdf'
    ]);
```

When I'm looking all I can really find is the dtOptions with the key inside of sAjaxSource with the url. I can't seem to find where or how it's binded and (presumably) running some sort of repeat on the table. I want to try and tap into wherever the data is being stored to run it through filters if possible.
I might be taking the wrong approach too, I'm not too sure. I just want to have a few buttons that will allow me to run some filters on the incoming information. Any help would be much appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks for reading!!

Update :

The closest I can come to seeing the scope it's binded too is using the row click event they have set up like so:

```
 $scope.message = '';
  $scope.someClickHandler = function(info) {
    console.log(info);
 };


 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('/listAllLessons')
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
    .withOption('rowCallback', function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $('td', nRow).bind('click', function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.someClickHandler(aData);
            });
        });
        return nRow;
    })
```

So this is returning the row clicked as an object just fine. I'm thinking perhaps maybe data-tables itself is handling all of the data? I can't quite tell.

Comment: you should show some of your relevant code, and maybe provide a better angularjs link. The one you provided just goes to AngularJS's homepage, nothing about directive data-tables

Comment: Sorry about that! link fixed.